# Aspect oriented programming Java - Get annotation parameters

Tags: java, annotations, aspectj

So I have defined 3 classes, as given below. What I am trying to do, is give input to an annotation, and then when an annotated function throws an exception, to use those parameters to do some stuff.

So basically, in the `CreateFluxoTicket` class in the `aferThrowing` function, I want to gain access to the "shortDescription" and "details" attributes.

I went through numerous links and answers, but I fail to get the parameters. One thing which I tried to do is shown below, but the parameter list is empty (The output is - "Parameter Types size = 0")

```
public class TemporaryClass {
    @Fluxo(shortDescription = "shortDescription", details = "details")
    public void tempFluxo() {
        System.out.println(50 / 0);
    }
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Fluxo {
    String shortDescription();
    String details();
}

@Aspect
public class CreateFluxoTicket {
    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "@annotation(metrics.annotations.Fluxo)", throwing = "e")
    public void afterThrowingException(JoinPoint jointPoint, Throwable e) {
        Signature signature = jointPoint.getStaticPart().getSignature();
        if (signature instanceof MethodSignature) {
            MethodSignature ms = (MethodSignature) signature;
            Class<?>[] parameterTypes = ms.getParameterTypes();
            System.out.println("Parameter Types size = " + parameterTypes.length);
            for (final Class<?> pt : parameterTypes) {
                System.out.println("Parameter type:" + pt);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the annotation to a parameter similar to the exception. Try this:

```
package metrics.aspect;

import metrics.annotations.Fluxo;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterThrowing;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

@Aspect
public class CreateFluxoTicket {
    @AfterThrowing(
        pointcut = "execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(fluxo)",
        throwing = "throwable"
    )
    public void afterThrowingException(
        JoinPoint thisJoinPoint,
        Fluxo fluxo,
        Throwable throwable
    ) {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint + " -> " + fluxo.shortDescription());
    }
}
```

As you can see, I also limited the pointcut to method `execution`s because otherwise `call`s would also trigger the advice and you would see the output twice.